Equipartition of Potential and Kinetic Energy in Linear Progressive Waves
While studying the properties of linear, progressive waves, a common property I've noticed among them is this: the energy in the wave is equally distributed, or equipartitioned between their two forms. Indeed, Lord Rayleigh first remarked on this observation in 1877, saying: 1

It  has  often  been  noticed,  in  particular   cases  of  progressive  waves, that  the  potential  and  kinetic  energies  are equal; but I do not call to mind any general treatment of the question.

As a few examples: in electromagnetic wave theory, for a monochromatic plane wave, the electric and magnetic energy densities are seen to be equal (see Griffiths, Section 9.2.3.); for a wave travelling on a string, the potential and kinetic energies are also equal (under some conditions, see here); for gravity waves on the surface of fluids, under the assumption of Airy wave theory, the (average) kinetic and potential energies are equal yet again as described here; and finally, for longitudinal waves as well.
Therefore, my question is: are the different (average) energies equal because of mere coincidence, or is there a more fundamental reason underlying this?
